# Inverting variable size block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetry

Given a block matrix $M$

$$\bf M=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a\ \mathbb{I}_{2} & \boldsymbol{\boldsymbol{A}}_{12} & \boldsymbol{A}_{13} & \boldsymbol{0_{(2,3)}}\\
\\
\boldsymbol{A_{21}} & a\ \mathbb{I}_{2} & \boldsymbol{A_{23}} & \boldsymbol{0_{(2,3)}}\\
\\
\boldsymbol{A_{31}} & \boldsymbol{A_{32}} & a\ \mathbb{I}_{2} & \boldsymbol{0_
{(2,3)}}\\
\boldsymbol{0_{(3,2)}} & \boldsymbol{0_{(3,2)}} & \boldsymbol{0_{(3,2)}} & b\ \mathbb{I}_{3}
\end{array}\right)$$

where $\bf 0_{(m,n)}$ is an $\ m\times n$ matrix with all entries equal to zero.

We need to find $\bf M^{-1}$ and I wondered if there were any theorems that allow me to invert this matrix block by block?

Also, how does the problem change for $A_{kl}=A_{lk},\ \ \ k,l=1,2,3$?

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that there is any practical useful formula for this general case.

For block $2\times 2$ matrices one generally use the [Schure complements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) (which is nothing more than the block version of Gaussian elimination). Theoretically you can recursively use this for a $n\times n$ ($n>2$) block matrix. However this is **not** a good idea because you will get overly complex formula without any practical value (with nested inverses etc...).

Beside this comment, observe that:
$$
M^{-1}=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
A^{-1}& 0 \\
0 & b^{-1}I
\end{array}
\right)
$$
with 
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
aI & A_{12} & A_{13} \\
A_{21} & aI & A_{23} \\
A_{31} & A_{32} & aI
\end{array}
\right)
$$
which is certainly the first simplification to considere.